# How to set custom resolution

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I am trying to make my old 1280x1024 monitor (connected on DVI-I-0) work with Ubuntu. The monitor I am trying is an old AOC VGA monitor connected via DVI-I to VGA adapter to Nvidia GTX960.
I have tried adding the mode with `xrandr`, but I was not successful.

I have tried running:

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00" 109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
```

and then

```
sudo xrandr --addmode 1280x1024_60.00
```

But the command returned an error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  47
  Current serial number in output stream:  48
```

Output of xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0 +
   1360x768       60.0     59.8  
   1152x864       60.0  
   800x600        72.2     60.3     56.2  
   680x384        60.0     59.8  
   640x480        59.9  
   512x384        60.0  
   400x300        72.2  
   320x240        60.1  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1360x768+1024+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
   1360x768       60.0*+
   1920x1080      60.0     59.9     50.0     30.0     25.0     24.0     60.1     60.0     50.0  
   1280x720       60.0     59.9     50.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   720x576        50.0     50.1  
   720x480        59.9  
   640x480        60.0     59.9     59.9  
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Output of 'cvt 1280 1024'

```
# 1280x1024 59.89 Hz (CVT 1.31M4) hsync: 63.67 kHz; pclk: 109.00 MHz
Modeline "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
```